# How to attach running executable to split

Tags: conemu

I have several running exes and need to attach them to ConEmu that was opened later. I do it using:

```
ConEmuC /guimacro attach(<pid>)
```

However it always creates new tab and I would like to see them in panes in single tab. As far as a get it the only way to achieve this is call first

```
ConEmu -cmd cmd -cur_console:s20V
```

to split console and then from opened split to start exe. But this does not work for me unfortunately because they are started by another tool and I can not modify code that spawns them. Is there a way to attach console to the split?